# how to store html in php variable?

Tags: php, html, css

i make a php page i want to store all the html in single php variable and then get using ajax,how i store this html in php variable name #msg,here is my code:

```
  $msg="<div id="new2"  style="background:#fff; width:779px; min-height:310px;"> 
               <table align="center"  width="779px" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" id="tb1">
                        <tr style="height:28px; font-size:12px;">
                          <td style="width:246px">Name</td>
                          <td style="width:145px">CITY</td> 
                          <td style="width:102px">ABCDEF</td>
                          <td style="width:71px">BUDGET</td> 
                          <td style="width:102px">MEMBERSHIP</td>
                          <td style="width:84px" id="td1">UNTIL</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                     <?php
                     $color='#DADDE2';
                     $business=getbussinesspagination(0,$start,$per_page);
                        if ($business){
                            while ($row = $business->fetch_assoc ()){
                             if($color=='#DADDE2')
                                    $color='#F9F9F9';
                             else
                                    $color='#DADDE2';                            
                      ?>   
                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:<?php echo $color; ?>; float:left"><p style="padding-left:45px; margin-top:8px;"><?php echo ($row['title']); ?></p></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="padding-left:30px; margin-top:8px;"><?php echo ($row['cityName']); ?></p></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="padding-left:40px; margin-top:8px;"><?php if($row['article']!=''){ echo 'A';} if($row['event']!=''){echo 'E'; } ?></p></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="padding-left:25px; margin-top:8px;"><?php echo ($row['credit']); ?></p></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="padding-left:25px; margin-top:8px;"><?php echo ($row['name']); ?></p></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="padding-left:10px; margin-top:8px;"><?php echo ($row['renewal_date']); ?></p></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><img src="messg.png" style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 
                        <?php 
                        }
                }

                        ?>  
                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 

                          <div id="m1" style="width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left"></div>
                          <div id="m2" style="width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m3" style="width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m4" style="width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m5" style="width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div>  
                          <div id="m6" style="width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"></div> 
                          <div id="m7" style="width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;"><img src="messg.png"  style="margin:8px 0 0 2px;"></div> 
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at your script? `$msg="<div id="new2"` you are opening the string wit `"` but not escaping the other `"`.

Comment: Quotes, quotes, quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I haven't missed anything:

```
<?php

$msg = "<div id=\"new2\"  style=\"background:#fff; width:779px; min-height:310px;\"> 
            <table align=\"center\"  width=\"779px\" cellpadding=\"0\"  cellspacing=\"0\" id=\"tb1\">
                <tr style=\"height:28px; font-size:12px;\">
                    <td style=\"width:246px\">Name</td>
                    <td style=\"width:145px\">CITY</td> 
                    <td style=\"width:102px\">ABCDEF</td>
                    <td style=\"width:71px\">BUDGET</td> 
                    <td style=\"width:102px\">MEMBERSHIP</td>
                    <td style=\"width:84px\" id=\"td1\">UNTIL</td>
                </tr>
            </table>";

$color='#DADDE2';

$business = getbussinesspagination(0,$start,$per_page);
if ($business)
{
    while ($row = $business->fetch_assoc ())
    {
        if($color=='#DADDE2')
            $color='#F9F9F9';
        else
            $color='#DADDE2';                            

        $msg .= "<div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:{$color}; float:left\"><p style=\"padding-left:45px; margin-top:8px;\">{$row['title']}</p></div>
        <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:{$color}\"><p style=\"padding-left:30px; margin-top:8px;\">{$row['cityName']}</p></div> 
        <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:{$color}\"><p style=\"padding-left:40px; margin-top:8px;\">".($row['article']!=''?'A':'').($row['event']!=''?'E':'')."</p></div> 
        <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:{$color}\"><p style=\"padding-left:25px; margin-top:8px;\">{$row['credit']}</p></div> 
        <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:{$color}\"><p style=\"padding-left:25px; margin-top:8px;\">{$row['name']}</p></div>  
        <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:{$color}\"><p style=\"padding-left:10px; margin-top:8px;\">{$row['renewal_date']}</p></div> 
        <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:{$color}\"><img src=\"messg.png\" style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> ";
    }
}

$msg .= "<div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#F9F9F9; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#F9F9F9;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 

    <div id=\"m1\" style=\"width:246px; height:28px; background:#DADDE2; float:left\"></div>
    <div id=\"m2\" style=\"width:145px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m3\" style=\"width:101px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m4\" style=\"width:70px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m5\" style=\"width:99px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div>  
    <div id=\"m6\" style=\"width:84px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"></div> 
    <div id=\"m7\" style=\"width:23px;   height:28px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1px;background:#DADDE2;\"><img src=\"messg.png\"  style=\"margin:8px 0 0 2px;\"></div> 
    </div>";

echo $msg;

?>
```

Comment: thanks very much Dainis Abolos

Answer (score 4):

You should make use of the [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. You could just copy the entire HTML content and pass it inside the `HEREDOC`. Your variables will also be parsed.

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example <b>of</b> string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc <b>syntax</b>.
EOD;

echo $str;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

[image]

Comment: Beware, the ending `EOD` has be without whitespace/any char prepended or appended.

Comment: @vonUbisch, Yes everything has been clearly specified in the manual and I had already linked it. Reading it is the least OP can do.

Comment: Yes, but he as an if statement in the middle of the texts.

Answer (score 1):

without heredoc you must not use `<?php` inside your string....

it should be like

```
$msg='<div id="new2"  style="background:#fff; width:779px; min-height:310px;"> 
               '.$another_variable_here_for_example.'<table align="center"  width="779px" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" id="tb1">...';
```

and if you need to add more code (like you do after the first `<?php`)
end the $msg = '...'; variable and add the rest later via $msg .= '...';

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of templating in PHP i use ob_get_contents()

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
include __DIR__ . '/your_template.php';
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use `$msg = '<p>Your HTML here</p>'` When you have `"` in your html code than use `'` to wrap the html. Works only when you use in your code only `"` quotes!

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to use heredoc syntax, and modify your code like below to use only variable in the middle of html (no function call)

```
$color='#DADDE2';
$business=getbussinesspagination(0,$start,$per_page);
if ($business){
  while ($row = $business->fetch_assoc ()){
  if($color=='#DADDE2')
    $color='#F9F9F9';
  else
    $color='#DADDE2';
}
else
{
}
$msg=<<<MYHTML
<div id="new2"  style="background:#fff; width:779px; min-height:310px;"> 
<table align="center"  width="779px" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" id="tb1">
<tr style="height:28px; font-size:12px;">
  <td style="width:246px">Name</td>
  <td style="width:145px">CITY</td> 
  <td style="width:102px">ABCDEF</td>
  <td style="width:71px">BUDGET</td> 
  <td style="width:102px">MEMBERSHIP</td>
  <td style="width:84px" id="td1">UNTIL</td>
</tr>
</table>
$business
MYHTML;
```

Alternatively, you can also use `ob_start();` and `ob_get_content();` to redirect the output into a variable you will use later.

```
ob_start();

// do all your code, nothing will be sent to screeen
echo '<div id="...';
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

var_dump($out1, $out2);