# how to store html in php variable for print?

Tags: php, html

I want to store html in a variable like `$var`. How to store this html in php variable?

**Here is my code:**

```
 $var="<div id=\"w1\" style=\"width:136px; height:28px; background:{$color}; float:left\"><p style=\"margin-top:6px; padding-left:40px;\">{$date=$row['entered']} {date('F', strtotime($date))}</p></div>                                                                <div id="w2" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($basic==''){ echo 0; } else { echo $basic; } ?></p></div>                               
                      <div id="w3" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($silver==''){ echo 0; } else { echo $silver; } ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w4" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($gold==''){ echo 0; } else {echo $gold; } ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w5" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($platinum==''){ echo 0; } else {echo $platinum; } ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w6" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>                         
                      <div id="w7" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px;"></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w8" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:20px;"><?php echo ($row['credit']); ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w9" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>                         
                      <div id="w10" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>
                     <div id="w10" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="padding-left:20px; margin-top:6px;"><?php if($row['article']!=''){ echo 'A';} if($row['event']!=''){echo 'E'; } ?></p></div>                         <div id="w11" style="width:79px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>                         
                     <div id="w12" style="width:109px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: you have asked similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908310/how-to-store-html-in-php-variable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933197/how-to-store-html-tag-in-php/21933323#21933323 and you have not yet tried to learn from that.Please stop posting same question with different contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HEREDOC`.

[php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$var = <<<MYSTRING
<div>My Div Tag</div>
<p>My Paragraph Tag</p>
MYSTRING;
```

Comment: This is a good answer provided arif does not need to perform conditional operations or loops in the html structure. The example posted contains conditions such as `if($platinum==''){ echo 0; } else {echo $platinum; }` which will require evaluation outside of the `HEREDOC`. Given the example code posted (and the benefit of IDE autocompletion), I believe the ob_start solution in my answer is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) which buffers output so you can re-use it later.

```
<?php
ob_start(); ?>
<div><p>My HTML</p></div>
<?php $var = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ob_start() and ob_get_contents() like this

```
<?php
   ob_start()
   $var = '<html>------</html>';
   $html = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<div id=\"w1\" style=\"width:136px; height:28px; background:{$color}; float:left\"><p style=\"margin-top:6px; padding-left:40px;\">{$date=$row['entered']} {date('F', strtotime($date))}</p></div>                                                                <div id="w2" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($basic==''){ echo 0; } else { echo $basic; } ?></p></div>                               
                      <div id="w3" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($silver==''){ echo 0; } else { echo $silver; } ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w4" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($gold==''){ echo 0; } else {echo $gold; } ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w5" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:30px;"><?php if($platinum==''){ echo 0; } else {echo $platinum; } ?></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w6" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>                         
                      <div id="w7" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px;"></p></div>                         
                      <div id="w8" style="width:69px; height:28px; float:left;margin:0 0 0 1px;  background:<?php echo $color; ?>"><p style="margin-top:6px; padding-left:20px;"><?php echo ($row['credit']); ?></p></div>
<?php
$html=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: This is invalid html markup. The quote identifiers are being escaped after a php close tag.

Comment: but i want to store all the divs in $var

Comment: Juste replace $html by $var  and remove " echo $html"
Like:
`<?php
$var=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>`